# ID invalid identifier in a query using JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I am getting the error . *ORA-00904: "TIPOINCIDE1_"."IDTIPO": invalid identifier* when i try to run a query in JPQL using annotetion @NamedQuery.

It works when do a query only with one entity but when create a query with multiple entities related it breaks.

This is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class TipoIncidencia {
    @Id
    @Column(name="IDTIPO")
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
    private int valor;
    
    public TipoIncidencia() {
        
    }
    
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

This is my Incidencia class, that creates the query and has the relation with TipoIncidencia:
ti is TipoIncidencia class.

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Incidencia.test", query="SELECT i.ti.descripcion FROM Incidencia i")
})
public class Incidencia {
    @Id
    private Date fecha;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="nif")
    private Conductor conductor;
    private String anotacion;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IDTIPO")
    private TipoIncidencia ti;
    public String getAnotacion() {
        return anotacion;
    }
    public void setAnotacion(String anotacion) {
        this.anotacion = anotacion;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

This is the call of the query, i am using DAO pattern:

```
public class IncidenciaDAO extends JpaDAO<Incidencia, String>{

    public IncidenciaDAO(EntityManager em) {
        super(em);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Incidencia> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Incidencia.findAll", Incidencia.class).getResultList();
    }
    
    public List ranking() {
        List m = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Incidencia.test").getResultList();
        return m;
    } 

}
```

Also going to add the Conductors class if it helps:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Conductor {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_COND")
    private int nif;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String direccion;
    private int cp;
    private String ciudad;
    private int puntos;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ASC_ID")
    private Asociacion asociacion;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="conductor")
    
    Set<Incidencia> incidencias;
    #Getters and setters
}
```

My tables are:

```
TipoIncidencia(id (PK), descripcion, valor)

Incidencia(fecha (PK), nif (PK, FK -> Conductor), anotacion, idtipo (FK -> TipoIncidencia))

Conductor(nif (PK), nombre, apellido, direccion, cp, ciudad, puntos)
```

Comment: Try specifying the referenced column name: @JoinColumn(name="IDTIPO", referencedColumnName = "IDTIPO").
Also... adding your actual 2 tables would help

Comment: Same error, trying your solution. Just added mi tables structure.

Comment: Ok so try removing the @Column(name) on the TipoIncidencia class, the actual column name is id so you don't need the annotation. Then just replace the @JoinColumn on Incidencia with @JoinColum(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
It should work

Comment: Now the output is: *ORA-00904: "INCIDENCIA0_"."ID": invalid identifier*

Comment: sorry my bad @JoinColum(name="idtipo", referencedColumnName="id")